# connect to remote mysql server (drupal)

Tags: php, mysql, cisco

I want to my developing drupal website to connect the mysql server which ip address is 192.168.1.104, while my developing machine ip is 10.0.0.2, there is a cisco router between the computers, 192.168.1.104 is connecting a boardband router which is connecting the cisco router, and 10.0.0.2 is connecting directly to the cisco router. I already set a access list at cisco router, which permit source 192.168.1.104:3306 to destination 10.0.0.2 on port 3306.

```
 $databases = array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'default' => 
        array (
          'database' => 'dbname',
          'username' => 'root',
          'password' => 'password',
          'host' => 'domainname.no-ip.com',
          'port' => '3306',
          'driver' => 'mysql',
          'prefix' => '',
        ),
      )
);
```

Firstly, 
1. is it possible to connecting the DB remotely? 
2. how about using root as username? is there any problem? 
3. can i connect the mysql server using local lan ip? is there any networking issue?

i've tested, there is an error

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\folder\includes\database\database.inc on line 304

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

**1. is it possible to connecting the DB remotely?**
Yes, simply specify the remote IP, in your case 192.168.1.104, as your host in your PHP connection string.

**2. how about using root as username? is there any problem?**
No problem, but a silly idea.  On your MySQL server add a new user called whatever you like (I usually go with "appname_remote") and set host for that user as being allowed from 10.0.0.2. This will allow your development machine to contact your mysql server remotely via this user, but no other machine (even if they know the credentials). This access restriction is much more secure.

**3. can i connect the mysql server using local lan ip? is there any networking issue?** 
You are routing across different subnets, the 10.0.0 and the 193.168.1 range.  Since you have a Cisco router in between the whole lot, you will have to configure the Cisco to allow routing between the subnets. The easiest way to test if it's already open is to try a ping from one machine against the other. If you get a ping response then routing is enabled. If not, then it's into Cisco's routing protocols you go (have fun there :) )

3) is more than likely the entire cause of your problem more than anything else.

Comment: i solved the problem, by adding a user grant it a permission to link by cisco router ip